# Auto layout issue with dynamically loaded XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode6, autolayout

I have an issue with auto layout and a particular UI flow I am trying to build.

Essentially, I have the following:

- A storyboard
- A `xib` called `UpdateYou.xib`
- A `xib` called `UpdateFilter.xib`

Within the `storyboard` is a scene for a `UIViewController` called `UpdateViewController` which in turn has a `UISegmentedControl` with two options and scrollview.

The general premise is that when the `UISegmentedControl` is in Option1 it loads the `UpdateYou.xib` in to the scrollview. This is constrained to the width of the parent View and expanded vertically as required.

However, when Option2 of the `UISegmentedControl` is selected the UpdateFilter `xib` is loaded but it is not constrained to the width of the parent view.

Below is a print out of the constraints (the first *** separated log is for the correctly laid out view):

```
2015-06-20 08:39:27.514 [42981:1543261] *************************************************
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7eeb0 UIView:0x7fc691d7d720.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7ef00 UIView:0x7fc691d7d720.top == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.topMargin>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7ef50 UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7fc691d7d720.trailing - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7efa0 UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7fc691d7d900.trailing - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7eff0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e4a0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fc691d7d900]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f040 UIView:0x7fc691d7d900.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f090 UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0.trailing == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f0e0 V:[UIView:0x7fc691d7d900]-(8)-[UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f130 UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f180 UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin == UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0.trailing - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f1d0 UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f220 V:[UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0]-(8)-[UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f270 V:[UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e9f0]>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d51190 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e4a0(0)]>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d55c60 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e4a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0 )>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d4f9a0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e9f0(0)]>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d66220 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e9f0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.bottom>
*************************************************

*************************************************
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7eeb0 UIView:0x7fc691d7d720.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7ef00 UIView:0x7fc691d7d720.top == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.topMargin>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7ef50 UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7fc691d7d720.trailing - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7efa0 UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7fc691d7d900.trailing - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7eff0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e4a0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fc691d7d900]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f040 UIView:0x7fc691d7d900.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f090 UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0.trailing == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f0e0 V:[UIView:0x7fc691d7d900]-(8)-[UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f130 UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f180 UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.trailingMargin == UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0.trailing - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f1d0 UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0.leading == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.leadingMargin - 16>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f220 V:[UISegmentedControl:0x7fc691d018b0]-(8)-[UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc691d7f270 V:[UIScrollView:0x7fc691d7bbd0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e9f0]>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d51190 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e4a0(20)]>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d55c60 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e4a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0 )>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d4f9a0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e9f0(0)]>
Constraint: <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc691d66220 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc691d7e9f0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0.bottom>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc69402d9e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0(375)]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc69402ed70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0(667)]>
Constraint: <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc69402db80 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fc691c40020 )>
Constraint: <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc69402d4e0 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fc691d7d5f0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fc691c40020 )>
*************************************************
```

I can see that the issue is with the additional constraints included in the second view but I know not why they are there or how they have even got there. I have checked the constraints in IB and they are not included.

I have tried to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` on the offending view but this makes the layout even worse!

The XIBs are added through the following code:

```
- (IBAction)onSegmentedControlValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        if (!updateProfileYou) {
            updateProfileYou = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UpdateProfileYou" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        }
        [self.scrollview.subviews[0] removeFromSuperview];
        [self.scrollview addSubview:updateProfileYou];
        [self.scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, updateProfileYou.frame.size.height)];
        break;
    case 1:
        if (!updateProfileFilters) {
            updateProfileFilters = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UpdateProfileFilters" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        }
        [self.scrollview.subviews[0] removeFromSuperview];
        [self.scrollview addSubview:updateProfileFilters];
        [self.scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, updateProfileFilters.frame.size.height)];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, add code for how u load the `xib` (after the user selected)

Comment: I don't see any constraints added in the scrollView for the newly added view, it may be the cause of your problem. Try adding some constraint after adding a view in you changeValue methode, something like : the view should be centered with the scrollView, it has to have the same width than the scrollview, the top have to be sticked to the scrollView, and finaly the scrollView's bottom has to be equal to the added view's bottom :)